# What h264_freq do I need to to improve video latency for h.264 on rpi 2 B?

Tags: streaming-video, config.txt

I'm looking at the following links to help modify my config.txt file:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md
http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

In there I see that the GPU can be overclocked, and that `h264_freq` can be set.

In googling use cases for `h264_freq`, all I can find is this thread on running quake:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=6201&start=50

In it, they have a bit of advice about overclocking the GPU, but not a lot of useable information for my situation. I am trying to send and receive html video with less than a second of video latency.

Right now, I am testing it in a loopback (the pi is outputting to itself) and by overclocking my gpu to 350 and `h264_freq` to 350, I was able to achieve faster results. The core is set to 500, as is the sdram.

I was reading on that link that there are optimal frequencies for setting each component so that they run faster.

Are these settings effective for h.264 encoding and decoding, as well as display, without risking shortening the life of my pi too much?

Right now I am using uv4l, but I plan on using the native v4l2 driver. I also have a heat sink on the Broadcom chip and plan on using a fan in the final unit.

Comment: [UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/news/) supports H264 hardware-encoded live streaming with **NO LATENCY**, full fps, 720p.